# PowerBI use primary key with null values

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

one question ...

It's possible to add a primary key in PowerBI with null value ?

My key for relation with DIM Table have a null value...  PowerBI issue with duplicate value ... I don't want a many to many relationship .
It's possible ?

Comment: No, it is not. Primary keys must always have value, and it must be unique.

Comment: By definition, a primary key cannot have duplicate values, null or otherwise.